# Cost of integrated tools in Dark Heresy

Tags: equipment, dark-heresy-1e

I'm creating a character in Dark Heresy 1e, and I've managed to find the cost of Integrated Weapons, the tool(s) I want, as well as the requirements I need for them, but I can't find any guidelines for integrated tools.

An example of something I want is an an Integrated stim injector. I want it to be concealable, not something as obvious as a medicae mechadendrite.

I have all the rulebooks, so where can I find the rules/guidelines to create an integrated tool?

Answer (score 1):

So after speaking to my GM, it appears that there is no specific rules for Integrated *Tools*, or even a *generic* rule for Integration costs. The only one we have been able to find is in the Lathe Worlds, p. 58; Table 2-6

| Name | Weight | Cost | Availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integrated Weapon Components | +0.5kg | 200 | Extremely Rare |

In our games, this can be treated as the cost for Integration for all items - weapons or tools; as the cost of the weapon or tool is separate.

<sup>In addition to this, the GM also allows a home rule to use XP at half "Cost" instead of Throne Gelt; depending on the Item and Creed of the Character. Eg a Techpriest with a Bionic arm can expend 100 XP to Integrate a Tool/Weapon into said arm)</sup>